# Dagger classes generated in build folder but unable to import them in a Java project using Dagger 2

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, dagger-2, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on the [Dagger 2 tutorial](https://dagger.dev/tutorial/). I am using vscode along with `build.gradle.kts`. I can see in my `build` folder that the Dagger prefixed classes have been generated. However, vscode LSP doesn't detect them and I cannot run the main function without getting an error saying `DaggerCommandRouterFactory cannot be resolved`.

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.7.10"
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google() // required for Dagger
}

application {
    mainClass.set("dagger.CommandLineAtm")
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
}

java {
    toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
}

dependencies {

    val daggerVersion = "2.46.1"

    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}")
    implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1");
    implementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1");

    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}")

    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.7.10")

}

kapt {
    mapDiagnosticLocations = true // include the Kotlin files into error reports
}
```

**Folder Structure**

```
- dagger
  - app
    - src/main
      - java/dagger
        - Command.java
        - CommandLineAtm.java
        - CommandRouter.java
        - CommandRouterFactory.java
        - Result.java
        - Status.java
    - build                              // Listing subset
      - generated
        - source
          - kapt
            - main/dagger
              - CommandRouter_Factory.java
              - DaggerCommandRouterFactory.java
```

Here's a screenshot of what I see in the gradle tab in vscode:

[image: Screenshot of the gradle tab]

1. I click on `build` and the build succeeds
2. If I click on `application > run`, I get a message saying `build successful` but the app doesn't actually run.

   [image: Result of clicking application > run in the gradle tab]
3. If I run by clicking on `run` above the `main` function in `CommandLineAtm`, I get the error

   > PS C:\Users\xyz\projects\dagger>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\xyz\projects\dagger'; & 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '@C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_blvz7kxfufnzn162kc06ngftq.argfile' 'dagger.CommandLineAtm'
   > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
   > DaggerCommandRouterFactory cannot be resolved
   >
   > at dagger.CommandLineAtm.main(CommandLineAtm.java:15)

Comment: try cleaning the project and rebuilding it. You can run the clean task in the Gradle tab and then run the build task again.

Comment: @JialeDu I tried that, but doesn't seem to be helping. Is there a way to specify a path where Java should look for classes in the project?